# UISearchbar do something before the keyboard shows up

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I'm having a UISearchBar. Now when I click on the searchbar the keyboard shows up.

I need to do something before my keyboard shows up. Changes in my layout.

So is there any way to do something before the keyboard shows up?

I thought maybe like this but it doesn't work:

```
-(BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [_searchBar resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}
```

But the keyboard doesn't hide.

Any one suggestions?

Comment: [_searchBar resignFirstResponder] - Is this one of the actions you want to do before the keyboard will be shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the UI changes in searchBarShouldBeginEditing before returning YES or NO.
If you dont want to show the keyboard return NO.

```
-(BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
   // Do the changes in UI

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: can you pls check whether the delegate method is called? Put a breakpoint or NSLog in searchBarShouldBeginEditing: and see if it reaches there

Comment: It reaches it. I've got a NSLog over there. When returning NO the keyboard keeps standing.

Comment: strange, it should work. Please post your searchBarShouldBeginEditing: method. And it will be helpfull if you can show us what UI changes you are doing before calling return NO;

Comment: There is just a call to my autolayout that resizes the whole layout. And then return YES. Because after it is resized it may show the keyboard. (Layout changes go via delegate to my container view )

Comment: Solved it. There was something wrong with my auto layout. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to get notified when the keyboard will show and hide.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onKeyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onKeyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}
```

Then add the two methods that will get called:

```
- (void)onKeyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{   
    NSLog(@"Keyboard will show!");
}

- (void)onKeyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"Keyboard will hide!");
}
```

And don't forget to stop listening when leaving the view:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to resize my layout before the keyboard shows up. And this notifies me but when my delegate is fired the keyboard already shows up so I don't have the time to resize my layout.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hide keyboard :
use only this viewwillAppear method on

```
[searchBarObje resignFirstResponsder];
```

You can simply call : for showing

```
[searchBarObje becomeFirstResponsder];

or you can use 
-(BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
   // Do the changes in UI
   [searchBar becomeFirstResponsder];
    return YES;
}
```

I think ., This will help you.

Comment: Resign doesn't dismiss the keyboard. It still pops up.

Comment: please check your IBoutlet is set properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the following standard iOS notification:

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];`